# Installing pull chain ceiling fan w/ light fixture. Two brown wires, two black wires, one red at the ceiling junction

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

Any ideas how to install? 
Just moved into an older home (built 1950s). Owner planned to install a new ceiling fan, but didn't get to it. Wondering which wires should attach to which...and if any wires should be left out and just capped off. Thanks for the direction and guidance.

Truly,

[image: ceiling junction]
[image: switch]
[image: switch]
[image: fan/light]
[image: back of switch...as far as it let me pull it]
[image: back of switch...another view]
[image: back of switch...another attempted view]

Comment: Can you post a shot that shows the back of the switchbox clearly please?

Comment: Thanks for checking in. I added a few more pics. Hope they loaded up more clearly for you to review. Keep me posted on any other shots you'd like to see.

Comment: Can you turn off the breaker and unmount (but do not unwire!) the lightswitch, then take a photo looking into the back of the switch box please?

Comment: Sure. I'll try and do that for you tomorrow morning. So you can take a look.

Comment: Tried to pull out the swtich as far as it would possibly allow. It was pretty taught. Hope that helps. It not, we'll make do with Jack's install recommendations. 
Thanks a million.

Comment: How do you want this fan to operate? And yes, Jack raises a *very* good point about the necessity of a fan-rated box in this situation

Comment: Thanks for asking. I simply wish to be able to use the pull chains. But, if it's as simple as just hooking the red and blue wires together in order to be able to use the switch, then that'll work well. I mainly just wanted a second opinion about which wires to hook together. The double white and double black confused me. I wasn't sure at the time if I should just use one of each. But I am happy that's it's ok to just hook the single black fan wire to the double black from ceiling...etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you will want the fan to operate by the pull chain and the light to operate by the switch. For clarity, those are black wires and white wires out of the ceiling. The black wire from the fan will get wire nutted to the two black wires from the ceiling. The white wire from the fan will get wire nutted to the two white wires from the ceiling and the red wire from the ceiling gets wire nutted to the blue wire from the fan.

Now the bad news. The pancake box in the ceiling is not rated for a ceiling fan. You will have to replace it with a ceiling fan rated pancake box. you can get them at many home stores or electrical supply stores.

Comment: I don't have a preference if the light is operated by only the pull chain or switch Whichever is the easiest/simplest. Should I hook up the ground from the fixture itself to the metal junction or anything? 
Sounds fairly simple the way you've explained hooking up the sets of wires. So I'll follow your lead. 
I'll also get to the store for a replacement fan rated pancake box. 

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @user115212  The light being operated by the switch is always a good idea since the switch is probably located by the door. I don't see a ground in there. you can verify a ground if you have a tester and go from black wire to  the box. You'll know better when you replace the box.

Comment: Good good. Yep, the switch is next to the front door entrance. No ground at the switch, but the unit has a ground. Should I just cap it off or screw it to the metal mount?

Comment: @user115212  If the wire has a metal shield, that could be a ground even though it's not used in the switch location. If no ground is present, cap it off.

Comment: Excellent. Sounds like a plan.